NAT table is never hit
I am trying to hit the nat table in my host1. For that I am logging the hits:
root@host1:~# iptables-save -t nat
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Wed Jul  3 16:08:26 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.0.43.10/32 -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat PREROUTING     : "
-A INPUT -d 192.0.43.10/32 -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat INPUT          : "
-A OUTPUT -d 192.0.43.10/32 -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat OUTPUT         : "
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.0.43.10/32 -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat POSTROUTING    : "
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul  3 16:08:26 2024

From another host, I am pinging 192.0.43.10. I see those requests entering host1 thorugh one of the interfaces:
root@host1:~# tcpdump -n icmp -i enx000ec6a42183
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enx000ec6a42183, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:33:48.203648 IP 192.168.200.10 > 192.0.43.10: ICMP echo request, id 69, seq 839, length 64
15:33:49.227659 IP 192.168.200.10 > 192.0.43.10: ICMP echo request, id 69, seq 840, length 64
15:33:50.251742 IP 192.168.200.10 > 192.0.43.10: ICMP echo request, id 69, seq 841, length 64

And leaving it through another interface:
root@host1:~# tcpdump -n icmp -i wlp2s0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:33:58.443770 IP 192.168.200.10 > 192.0.43.10: ICMP echo request, id 69, seq 849, length 64
15:33:59.467667 IP 192.168.200.10 > 192.0.43.10: ICMP echo request, id 69, seq 850, length 64
15:34:00.491803 IP 192.168.200.10 > 192.0.43.10: ICMP echo request, id 69, seq 851, length 64
15:34:01.515733 IP 192.168.200.10 > 192.0.43.10: ICMP echo request, id 69, seq 852, length 64

But the nat table is never hit: no logs are shown at all.
If I do the same for the filter or the mangle tables, I see the packets arriving.
When is the nat table used?
EDIT
This is the complete iptables:
 Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [26:3977]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:616]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [26:3977]
:INPUT ACCEPT [19:3389]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [7:588]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:616]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [17:1204]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat PREROUTING     : "
-A INPUT -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat INPUT          : "
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat OUTPUT         : "
-A POSTROUTING -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix "nat POSTROUTING    : "
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [19:3389]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [7:588]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:616]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul  3 16:24:43 2024


Pretty large sequence numbers, that hints me at that you're started ping and then added rules. Restart your ping (or start another), you should see a single LOG record. The NAT table is traversed only once per connection, in one direction; then, the record in the conntrack table is created and that table is considered first. If there's a match (a connection exists that the packet in question can be related to), the NAT table isn't consulted at all. This is documented.

@NikitaKipriyanov thanks, but that is not the problem. I restart my ping regularly, and it never hits (I just did it again to confirm). Are icmp packages traversing the nat table at all? Regarding conntrack table, do you have a link to the documented behaviour? The only thing I find is the manual of the conntrackutility. BTW, this utility shows no connections with conntrack -L

Yes, they do. Show the complete firewall (just iptables-save), maybe you have NOTRACK somewhere, or something else can influence it? // I explained its behavior several times on ServerFault, with links to LARTC.

@NikitaKipriyanov added. Thanks!

@NikitaKipriyanov I think ChatGPT is on to something: https://chatgpt.com/share/9678a8fe-1188-4cb8-abd9-070fe454ccfb. It seems logging is not supported for the nat table. The test I am doing will never work. Funny that the system does not complain about it.

Probably. I don't remember trying to log exactly in the NAT table. The fact it's traversed once might actually be the reason it never does logging. Anyway, even if that's the case there are workarounds, for instance, TRACE target which would log all the chains the packet was put through. // ChatGPT can never provide a source reference, without it, it's just a speculation. This is why, by the way, LLM answers are frowned upon here, because we desire facts, not opinions or speculations.

@NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for the details. I will check the TRACE. Regarding LLM, your point is valid, and it has definitely weaknesses. But it would be a mistake not to recognize some strengths. For me, it is the fact that it is always on, at the click of a button, and that it leads you in an understandable manner to places that you did not previously consider. It might be wrong - it often is - but in the process of talking to it you become aware of real facts that would take much more effort for you to find out or understand. It's a tool. A good tool.
